# Laravel 5.2 Dynamic Role and Permission assigning and checking

Tags: php, laravel-5, entrust

I'm using Laravel 5.2 with Entrust to manage users roles and permissions. Till now I've been protecting my routes bu using middlewares like this :

```
Route::get( 'roles', [ 'as' => 'roles.index', 'uses' => 'RoleController@index', 'middleware' => ['permission:role-list|role-create|role-edit|role-delete'] ] );
```

But now I want to check the roles and permission dynamically not by manually adding in the middlewares. I want to create Permissions and assign them to Roles and the assign the roles to the Users. And want to check the roles during runtime like in base controller or somewhere else. How can I achieve this system. Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.
You will have to make the following tables.

- users, roles &  permissions.
- Pivot tables: role_user  & permission_role.
- Models: User, Role and Permission.

for details watch this tutorial.
https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/16
and Code is available at https://github.com/laracasts/laravel-5-roles-and-permissions-demo